# Is there a way to change the Language used for properties in the xml-files of an xlsx-File created using OpenXml in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, xml, openxml

I'm creating an Excel .xlsx File using OpenXml. Everything works fine, except when I open the File, excel said that there are problems with the file and offers to repair it. (Everything is displayed like it should be.) After some research I stumbled upon some posts about language specific property-values. For Example OpenXML writes "TRUE" and "FALSE" but my German Excel Version wants "WAHR" and "FALSCH". And this is why Excel needs to repair the file. The log of the Excel repair just says "Repaired Cell-Information in the Worksheet"

I've changed my Excel and system language from German to English (US) and now everything works fine and the file opens without a repair message.

Is there a way to work around this, since this is not a permanent Solution.

EDIT: Maybe the problem could also be somewhere else but everything i tried seems to confirm this suspicion. But then this should also occur when opening a Excel-File created by someone with English language, but that doesn't seem to happen.

This is an example of how I write to the File.

```cs
                   for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
                {
                    row = new Row();
                    for (int j = 0; j < columncount; j++)
                    {
                        bool isNumeric = double.TryParse(result[i,j], out double n);
                        if (isNumeric)
                        {
                            row.Append(ConstructCell(result[i,j], CellValues.Number));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row.Append(ConstructCell(result[i, j], CellValues.String));
                        }                                            
                    }

                    sheetData.AppendChild(row);
                }
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

            }
        }

        private Cell ConstructCell (string value, CellValues dataType)
        {
            return new Cell()
            {
                CellValue = new CellValue(value),
                DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(dataType)
            };
        }
```